# Proving cot identity using Euler identities

Tags: trigonometry, complex-numbers

I'm trying to prove that $\cot(2\theta)+\csc(2\theta)=\cot(\theta)$. I'm using that
$$\sin(\theta)=\frac{1}{2i}(e^{i\theta}-e^{-i\theta})\qquad \cos(\theta)=\frac{1}{2}(e^{i\theta}+e^{-i\theta})$$
So plugging them into the formula $\frac{\cos(\theta)}{\sin(\theta)}=\cot(\theta)$, what pops out is
$$\cot(2\theta)=i\left(\frac{e^{2i\theta}+e^{-2i\theta}}{e^{2i\theta}-e^{-2i\theta}}\right)\\
\csc(2\theta)=2i\left(\frac{1}{e^{2i\theta}-e^{-2i\theta}}\right)\\
\cot(\theta)=i\left(\frac{e^{i\theta}+e^{-i\theta}}{e^{i\theta}-e^{-i\theta}}\right)$$
So putting the first two together for the LHS I get:
$$i\left(\frac{e^{2i\theta}+e^{-2i\theta}}{e^{2i\theta}-e^{-2i\theta}}\right)+2i\left(\frac{1}{e^{2i\theta}-e^{-2i\theta}}\right)=i\left(\frac{e^{2i\theta}+e^{-2i\theta}+2}{e^{2i\theta}-e^{-2i\theta}}\right)$$
What I don't understand is how to manipulate this to become $\cot(\theta)=i\left(\frac{e^{i\theta}+e^{-i\theta}}{e^{i\theta}-e^{-i\theta}}\right)$.

I can't find a simple factorisation to pull the $e^2$s and the $2$ out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$
\dfrac{e^{2i\theta}+e^{-2i\theta}+2}{e^{2i\theta}-e^{-2i\theta}}=\dfrac{e^{4i\theta}+1 +2e^{2i\theta}}{e^{4i\theta}-1}=\dfrac{(e^{2i\theta}+1)^2}{(e^{2i\theta}+1)(e^{2i\theta}-1)}=
\dfrac{e^{2i\theta}+1}{e^{2i\theta}-1}
=
\dfrac{e^{i\theta}+e^{-i\theta}}{e^{i\theta}-e^{-i\theta}}
$$

Answer (score 3):

Hint : $\exp(2it) + 2 + \exp(-2it) = (\exp(it) + \exp(-it))^2$

And in the denominator factorize

Answer (score 1):

$$i\left(\frac{e^{2i\theta}+e^{-2i\theta}+2}{e^{2i\theta}-e^{-2i\theta}}\right)$$
$$
e^{2i\theta}+e^{-2i\theta}+2 = e^{-2i\theta} \left[ 
\left( e^{2i\theta} \right)^2 + 2 e^{2i\theta} +1 \right] 
= e^{-2i\theta}  \left[ 
e^{2i\theta}  +1 \right]^2
$$
$$
e^{2i\theta}-e^{-2i\theta} = e^{-2i\theta} \left[ \left( e^{2i\theta} \right)^2 -1 \right]
$$ $$
= e^{-2i\theta} \left[ 
e^{2i\theta}  +1 \right] \left[ 
e^{2i\theta}  -1 \right]
$$

Cancel the $e^{-2i\theta} $ and one factor of $\left[ 
e^{2i\theta}  +1 \right]$ to obtain your result.